# Trying to pull from remote repositry - fatal error: access denied

Tags: git, git-pull, pull

I already new with git trying to setup a reposity on server machine to be as a remote repositry and pull from my machine, note that are the two machines on the same network.

Server:

```
git init mba
git add *
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin git://IP/mba.git
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

Local:

```
git pull origin master
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported
```

I don't know where is the problem, please help.
I appreceate your time.

Comment: Is the remote one you already created under your account or an organization's account that you have read access to?

Comment: Additionally, what's with the use of `git daemon`? I don't think your `base-path` seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i found the solution. 
the problem was in the path of repositry in server i was create a remote repositry with path and pull from another path :D.

thanks all.